# GeoFire retrieve all queries within a range when moving.

Tags: firebase, geofire

I'm trying to retrieve all elements from my GeoFire database when moving. For example: when walking around I want to retrieve in realtime the locations of elements around me (moving or not moving).

If I use the following code:

```
var geoQuery = geoFire.query({
            center: [52.35500, 4.931000],
            radius: 0.1 //kilometers
});

var onKeyEnteredRegistration = geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(key, location, distance) {
            console.log(key + " entered query at " + location + " (" + distance + " km from center)");
        });
```

I only receive updates when the keys are changing position (and entering my query). Is there a possibility to retrieve all elements within a certain range as a sort of a snapshot? And from there monitor realtime?

I could of course query the whole database and then use

```
GeoFire.distance(location1, location2)
```

But this looks like a very expensive option.

Answer (score 2):

You can call [`GeoQuery.updateCriteria(newQueryCriteria)`](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js#geoqueryupdatecriterianewquerycriteria) to update the center of the query as you move.

Note that you probably want to register a `key_exited` callback as well.

---

*Check out the [GeoFire API Reference](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js#api-reference)*

Comment: The problem is that still the EXISTING keys will not be displayed. Only a new key, or key that changes position will be registered. My goal is to: retrieve all keys within a certain range based on their last position relative to my geoQuery.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. When the GeoFire query's initial state loads, all keys within the radius "enter" the query. You can use `geoQuery.on("ready", callback)`. From the docs: *"`ready` fires once when this query's initial state has been loaded from the server. The `ready` event will fire after all other events associated with the loaded data have been triggered. `ready` will fire again once each time `updateQuery()` is called, after all new data is loaded and all other new events have been fired."* You can push these keys to an array/object and maintain a complete list.

Comment: I'm probably begin a big noob right now, and doing something stupid. Thanks for taking the time. But I cannot find a way to display the initial keys, if I add new keys or change keys everything works fine.

If I have a database with 10 keys with gps coordinates that are not moving. I want to display those 10 keys within a given range (given in my query). With the key_exited and key_entered I can only display changes, I want to display also the non-moving keys.

Comment: I just rebuild my code, and now indeed all keys are displaying on the key_entered function. I don't know exactly why, but I am very happy it's working. Thank you for answering because it forced me to look into the code again I was already looking into other options :) Thanks It's appreciated!

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad you were able to figure it out. For more inspiration, you can always check out the examples Firebase has put together: https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/tree/master/examples

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to query whole database. You can store your places in a variable and calculate new distances when your current position (query center) changes.

```
private places: any;

var onKeyEnteredRegistration = geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(key, location, distance) {
  this.places.push({ key, location, distance });
});

var onKeyExitedRegistration = geoQuery.on("key_exited", function(key, location, distance) {
  this.places = this.places.filter(place => place.key !== key);
});

updatePlacesDistance(currentLocation) {
  this.places.map(place => {
    place.distance = GeoFire.distance(currentLocation, place.location);
  });
}
```